# how to add cascade constraint on existing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table t1 which has a primary key t1id.I have another table t2 which has column t1id which is a forign key to t1id of t1 table.Please see the query

```
create table T1
(
    t1idint primary key IDENTITY(1,1),

    Name varchar(200) not null

);




create table T2
(
    t2idint primary key IDENTITY(1,1),

   t1id int,
    nod bigint,
    foreign key ( t1id) references T1(t1id)
);
```

and many more tables linked with T2 table that I am not showing here.

I have inserted some values in both Tables T1 and T2.

Now to delete a row from T1 ,I have to 1st delete a row from T2 and then only I can be able to delete a row from T1 because of foriegn key relationship.

So I thought adding cascading constraint would be good idea

I tried like the below

```
  ALTER TABLE T2
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_T2id
FOREIGN KEY (t1id)
REFERENCES T1(t1id)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

but I got the below error

*Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'fk_t1id' on table 'T2' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.*

Comment: Your sample code isn't good enough to display your observed behaviour (after I fix it to actually work). Edit it to make sure the error actually shows :) Also, usually you would simply add the `on delete cascade` to the existing constraint, rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself in your situation many times, but never used a cascade. I do a SP that will get the ID I want to delete and I do the delete myself in a transaction. See example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spConfiguration_Table1_Del]
@ID int
AS

Declare @ERR int 
set @ERR = 0
begin tran

    DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ID = @ID
    set @ERR = @@Error

    if @ERR = 0 begin
    DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table3 WHERE ID = @ID)
    set @ERR = @@Error
    end

    if @ERR = 0 begin 
    DELETE FROM Table3 WHERE ID = @ID 
    set @ERR = @@Error
    end

if @ERR = 0 commit tran
else rollback tran
```

This way you can control the way the delete happens, also if there is an error in deleting from one table, the transaction will rollback all the deleted rows and you keep your data consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Why to call procedure,I can write 3 different quries also

Comment: Indeed, but using a SP is somehow more easy going. As you only pass your ID once if you repeat many times the queries, it's also fewer lines of code to write.

Comment: can you tell  me How to use it?Also can you tell me if its right or not http://pastie.org/9934457

Comment: It looks good, but only you can tell if it's right or not as it depends on the table dependencies. You can use it by calling 'exec spConfiguration_Table1_Del 1256' where 1256 is the id that you want to be deleted.

Comment: do i have to run above codes all the time and after that exec spConfiguration_Table1_Del 1256

Comment: You should read about Stored Procedures in MSSQL and what they are used for. SP are like a function, you creat in once and then you run it as many times as you want by calling it. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: If I want to make some changes in the existing SP then i what I have to doi?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345356.aspx please take some time and read about StoredProcedures from msdn. They are very easy to use/modify/create/delete. Just take 10 minutes and read.

Comment: I am basically a java programmer so not have much knowledge about Sql.Thanka again for helping,+1

Comment: I can see that, but the link I gave you has all the information you need about Stored Procedures. You can edit a SP from SSMS ( SQL Server Management Studio) or by running the ALTER PROCEDURE spConfiguration_Table1_Del

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70624/discussion-between-springlearner-and-ciucas).